# What version on Ubuntu must I download to run on an Intel d865gbf motherboard

Tags: system-installation

Firstly I am very new to Linux i.e. never used it before (have used plenty of other OS) I have an old desktop computer -motherboard in an intel d865gbf and I would like to run Ubuntu linux on it. What version must I download and where do I get it? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you checked the system requirements page at the Ubuntu site?

Comment: It depends on RAM size. For at least 2 Gb Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS will be good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on an older machine, installing [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu) will probably be your best bet. Check out the info on the [requirement page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) to educate yourself further.